# mongoose.save() not saving all fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

**im new to node and express so this might not be clear**

I am using mongodb to make a mini twitter clone.
When you submit your tweet (called mew in my app) it makes a post request. even though the data is getting saved, its only saving __v _id and the timestamps

**things I've tried**

1. emptying my collection
2. using longhand for setting types
3. different browsers
4. removing timestamps
5. XHR instead of fetch

**my code**

**backend:**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { log } = console;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://***:***@twitter-ci8qa.gcp.mongodb.net/twitter?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    content: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
var p = [];
var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
const { connection } = mongoose;
connection.on("open", () => log("MongoDB: Connected"));
function isValidMew(mew) {
  return (
    mew.name &&
    mew.name.toString().trim() !== "" &&
    mew.content &&
    mew.content.toString().trim !== ""
  );
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Post.find().then((p) => {
    old = p;
    res.json(p);
  });
});
app.post("/mews", (req, res) => {
  if (isValidMew(req.body)) {
    const newMew = {
      name: req.body.name.toString(),
      content: req.body.content.toString(),
    };
    p = [...p, newMew];
    log(p);
    var postCollection = new Post(p);
    postCollection.markModified("twitter.posts");
    postCollection.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("worked");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(500);
    res.json({
      err: "invalid request",
    });
  }
});
app.listen(7777, () => {
  log("listening");
});
```

**frontend:**

```
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const loading = document.querySelector(".loading");
const API_URL = "http://localhost:7777/mews";
loading.style.display = "none";
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formdata = new FormData(form);
  const name = formdata.get("name");
  const content = formdata.get("content");
  const mew = {
    name,
    content,
  };
  loading.style.display = "";
  form.style.display = "none";
  fetch(API_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(mew),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  fetch("http://localhost:7777/")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => alert(JSON.stringify(data)));
  form.style.display = "initial";
  loading.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing a new `Post`-object to the `Post`-Model inside the `/mews`-handler, but instead you are passing an array as you're spreading the `p`-array together with `newMew` and thus creating a new array. So changing this to:

```
...
const newMew = {
      name: req.body.name.toString(),
      content: req.body.content.toString(),
    };
   
log(newMew);
const postCollection = new Post(newMew);
...
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: Happy to help, would be nice if you accepted my answer, thank you!